# SessionDelegate.swift file did not implement URLSessionDelegate's session didReceive challenge

Tags: swift, alamofire

I was using Charles with Alamofire but get a -999 error, howerver AFNetworking works well, I found that AFNetworking implemented urlSession:didReceiveChallenge Alamofire did not, is there any reason for that?

Comment: No, there is no reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire instead implements [`urlSession(_:task:didReceive:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411595-urlsession) which operates at the `URLSessionTask`-level rather than the `URLSession`-level. This allows Alamofire to more easily offer per-`Request` authentication errors when implementing certificate pinning.